# Covering of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the complement of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $p$ be a closed point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ for some integer $n$ and $\{U_i\}$ be an affine open covering of $\mathbb{P}^n\backslash p$. Does there exists an open set in the covering, say $U_0$ for which $U_0 \cup p$ is open in $\mathbb{P}^n$?

**A slightly modified question**: Assumption as before. Does there exist an open set, say $U$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ containing $p$ such that $U\backslash p$ is contained in one of the open sets $U_i$?

Comment: It's true if $n = 1$, or if you're working over a finite field. Otherwise it's almost certainly false.

Comment: Why do you think this is "almost certainly false" in the case when $n \ge 2$ and the underlying field is $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: To flesh out @oxeimon's comment: Let $p=[1,0,0] \in \mathbf P^2$. Then $\mathbf P^2 \setminus p$ is covered by $U_1 = \{y \neq 0\}$ and $U_2 = \{z \neq 0\}$. But neither of those remains open when you add in $p$. Analogous arguments will work for any $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @Dubh: I have slightly edited the question. Does this counterexample work for this question as well?